# How to search and retrieve whole lines from a txt file using Keyword

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, search, arraylist

```
searchfile =open('test.txt','r')
    for line in searchfile:
        if line in array: print line
    searchfile.close()
```

The search works except i have a keywords.txt document containing simple words like 'green, blue etc' (all on their own line) I then have a document with text such as 'my shirt is green' when i use this code it wont find anything but if I change the sentence in the txt file to just one word it will find it. I need it to search a document for keywords and then display the whole line that it was in.

Answer (score 1):

```
searchfile = open('keywords.txt', 'r')
infile = open('text.txt', 'r')

for keywords in searchfile:
    for lines in infile:
        if keywords in lines:
           print lines
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
searchfile = None
with open('test.txt','r') as f:
    searchfile = f.readlines()
    f.close()

for line in searchfile:
    for word in array:
        if word in line:
            print line
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
searchFile = open('keywords.txt','r')
file = open('text.txt','r') 
file1 = file.readlines()  
file.close()
for key in searchFile:
    for line in file1:
        if key in Line:
             print (line)
```

Answer (score 0):

Make keywords a `set`, the check if any word in the line is in the set:

```
with open('search.txt','r') as f1, open("keywords.txt") as f2:
    st = set(map(str.rstrip, f2))
    for line in f1:
        if any(word in st for word in  line.split()):
            print(line)
```

If you don't split `"green" in  'my shirt is greenish' -> True`. You also have to take into account punctuation and case.

If you want to ignore case and remove punctuation, you can use `str.lower` and `str.strip`:

```
from string import punctuation
with open('search.txt','r') as f1, open("keywords.txt") as f2:
    st = set(map(str.rstrip, f2))
    for line in f1:
        if any(word.lower().strip(punctuation) in st for word in line.split()):
            print(line)
```